# Google Users: List users data of a specific group

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-api-nodejs-client

I am in the need of listing the users data belonging to a specific group within the organization. The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users) does not specify if this is possible. I was really hoping there could be some kind of query that would allow this. For example `email in (1@domain.com,2@domain.com)`. However, I don't see that being possible. The only way I could think to accomplish this would be:

1. Get a list of all the members in the group (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/list)
2. Get each user data by email (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get)

The problem with the above approach is that if a group contains 50+ members, this means that I have to make all that amount of requests, which is counter productive. Imagine how long that would take.

Any ideas? Greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I don’t think you can skip this two step process, but you can speed it up using [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch). This
allows you to request up to 1000 calls in a single request. The steps would be:

1. Make a batch request to get all the members of all the groups you want (using `members.list`).
2. Make a batch request to get all the user info that you need using their id (using `user.get`).

Notice that the data in the result won’t be sorted, but they will be tagged by `Content-ID`.

### References

- [Sending Batch Requests (Directory API)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch)
- [Method: members.list (Directory API)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/members/list)
- [Method: users.get (Directory API)](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/get)

Answer (score 1):

I thought about the batching request a couple of hours after I posted the question. The problem with Node JS is that it does not has built in support for batch requests, unlike the php client library for example; Therefore, I had to spent some time implementing support for it on my own since I was not able to find any example. I'll share the solution in case it helps someone else or for my future reference.

```js
async function getGroupMembersData(){
  const groupEmail = "group@domain.com"; //google group email
  const groupMembers = await getGroupMembers(groupEmail).catch(error=>{
    console.error(`Error querying group members: ${error.toString()}`);
  });
  if(!groupMembers){ return; }
  const url = "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/admin/directory_v1";
  const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"];
  const requests = [];
  for(let i=0; i<groupMembers.length; ++i){
    const user = groupMembers[i];
    const request = {
      email: user,
      endpoint: `GET directory_v1/admin/directory/v1/users/${user}?fields=*`
    };
    requests.push(request);
  }
  const batchRequestData = await batchProcess(url, scopes, requests).catch(error=>{
    console.error(`Error processing batch request: ${error.toString()}`);
  });
  if(!batchRequestData){ return; }
  const usersList = batchRequestData.map(i=>{
    return i.responseBody;
  });
  console.log(usersList);
}

//get group members using group email address
async function getGroupMembers(groupKey){
  const client = await getClient(scopes); //function to get an authorized client, you have to implement on your own
  const service = google.admin({version: "directory_v1", auth: client});
  const request = await service.members.list({
    groupKey,
    fields: "members(email)",
    maxResults: 200
  });
  const members = !!request.data.members ? request.data.members.map(i=>i.email) : [];
  return members;
}

//batch request processing in groups of 100
async function batchProcess(batchUrl, scopes, requests){
  const client = await getClient(scopes); //function to get an authorized client, you have to implement on your own
  let results = [];
  const boundary = "foobar99998888"; //boundary line definition
  let batchBody = ""; const nl = "\n";
  const batchLimit = 100; //define batch limit (max supported = 100)
  const totalRounds = Math.ceil(requests.length / batchLimit);
  let batchRound = 1;
  let batchItem = 0;
  let roundLimit = batchLimit;
  do{
    roundLimit = roundLimit < requests.length ? roundLimit : requests.length;
    //build the batch request body
    for(batchItem; batchItem<roundLimit; batchItem++){
      const requestData = requests[batchItem];
      batchBody += `--${boundary}${nl}`;
      batchBody += `Content-Type: application/http${nl}`;
      batchBody += `Content-Id: <myapprequest-${requestData.email}>${nl}${nl}`;
      batchBody += `${requestData.endpoint}${nl}`;
    }
    batchBody += `--${boundary}--`;
    //send the batch request
    const batchRequest = await client.request({
      url: batchUrl,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": `multipart/mixed; boundary=${boundary}`
      },
      body: batchBody
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.log("Error processing batch request: " + error);
    });
    //parse the batch request response
    if(!!batchRequest){
      const batchResponseData = batchRequest.data;
      const responseBoundary = batchRequest.headers["content-type"].split("; ")[1].replace("boundary=", "");
      const httpResponses = batchResponseParser(batchResponseData, responseBoundary);
      results.push(...httpResponses);
    }
    batchRound++;
    roundLimit += batchLimit;
  } while(batchRound <= totalRounds);
  return results;
};

//batch response parser
function batchResponseParser(data, boundary){
  const nl = "\r\n";
  data = data.replace(`--${boundary}--`,"");
  const responses = data.split(`--${boundary}`);
  responses.shift();
  const formattedResponses = responses.map(i=>{
    const parts = i.split(`${nl}${nl}`);
    const responseMetaParts = (parts[0].replace(nl, "")).split(nl);
    let responseMeta = {};
    responseMetaParts.forEach(part=>{
      const objectParts = part.split(":");
      responseMeta[objectParts[0].trim()] = objectParts[1].trim();
    });
    const responseHeadersParts = parts[1].split(nl);
    let responseHeaders = {};
    responseHeadersParts.forEach(part=>{
      if(part.indexOf("HTTP/1.1") > -1){
        responseHeaders.status = part;
      } else {
        const objectParts = part.split(":");
        responseHeaders[objectParts[0].trim()] = objectParts[1].trim();
      }
    });
    const reg = new RegExp(`${nl}`, "g");
    const responseBody = JSON.parse(parts[2].replace(reg, ""));
    const formatted = {
      responseMeta: responseMeta,
      responseHeaders: responseHeaders,
      responseBody: responseBody
    };
    return formatted;
  });
  return formattedResponses;
}
```